# Implement Fibonacci with `iterate`

Tags: haskell, fibonacci-sequence

I implemented the Fibonacci sequence using `iterate`.

```
import Data.List

fib :: Int -> Maybe Int
fib n 
 | n < 0     = Nothing
 | otherwise = (fmap (snd . fst)) $ find (\(_,i) -> n == i) (zip res [0..])

res :: [(Int, Int)]
res = iterate f (0,1)

f :: (Num a, Num b) => (a, a) -> (a, a)
f (x, y) = (y,x+y)
```

**Testing**

```
> fib (-1)
Nothing
> fib 0
Just 1
> fib 2
Just 2
> fib 3
Just 3
> fib 4
Just 5
> fib 5
Just 8
> fib 6
Just 13
```

Please review it.

Answer (score 8):

In my opinion, `Maybe` is too cumbersome here.  I'd consider `fib (-1)` to be ill-defined, and I'd let it just crash with an `error`.

By your convention, the Fibonacci sequence is

> 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, …

I would prefer to see it start earlier, such that `fib 0` is 0:

> 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, ….

The outputs can get pretty big.  I suggest using `Integer` instead of `Int`.

You're using a very convoluted way to extract the *n*<sup>th</sup> item from a list.

### Suggested solution

```
import Data.List (iterate)

fib :: Int -> Integer
fib n = fst $ sequence !! n
  where
    sequence = iterate (\(x, y) -> (y, x + y)) (0, 1)
```

You could also use the point-free style:

```
fib :: Int -> Integer
fib = (!!) $ map fst $ iterate (\(x, y) -> (y, x + y)) (0, 1)
```

For that matter, you could just define the infinite sequence

```
fibonacciSequence = map fst $ iterate (\(x, y) -> (y, x + y)) (0, 1)
```

… and let the caller do whatever they want with it, including extracting specific entries using `!!`.

#### Behaviour

```
*Main> fib (-1)
*** Exception: Prelude.!!: negative index
*Main> fib 0
0
*Main> fib 1
1
*Main> fib 2
1
*Main> fib 3
2
*Main> fib 4
3
*Main> fib 5
5
```